# Setting UTF-8 in MariaDB server ignores character_set_system

Tags: database, unicode, character-encoding, mariadb

I have the following `Dockerfile` definition file for a MariaDB server:

```yaml
version: "3.8"

...

services:
  database:
    command: ["mysqld", "--character-set-server=utf8mb4", "--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci"]
    container_name: mariadb
    environment:
      MARIADB_DATABASE: sample_database
      MARIADB_INITDB_SKIP_TZINFO: "true"
      MARIADB_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/mariadb_user_password
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/root_user_password
      MARIADB_USER: mariadb
      TZ: "Etc/UTC" # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones
    image: docker.io/library/mariadb:10.6-focal # https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb/
    networks:
      - global-network
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    restart: on-failure
    secrets:
      - mariadb_user_password
      - root_user_password
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - "database-volume:/var/lib/mysql"
```

I'm not quite versed on this topic, but if I would like to check the character- and collation-set used by the server, I usually do execute these queries:

```sql
> show variables like 'char%';
+------------------------+--------------------------+
|Variable_name           |Value                     |
+------------------------+--------------------------+
|character_set_client    |utf8mb4                   |
|character_set_connection|utf8mb4                   |
|character_set_database  |utf8mb4                   |
|character_set_filesystem|binary                    |
|character_set_results   |utf8mb4                   |
|character_set_server    |utf8mb4                   |
|character_set_system    |utf8mb3                   |
|character_sets_dir      |/usr/share/mysql/charsets/|
+------------------------+--------------------------+


> show variables like 'collation%';
+--------------------+------------------+
|Variable_name       |Value             |
+--------------------+------------------+
|collation_connection|utf8mb4_unicode_ci|
|collation_database  |utf8mb4_unicode_ci|
|collation_server    |utf8mb4_unicode_ci|
+--------------------+------------------+
```

My understanding is that the settings that I have: `--character-set-server=utf8mb4` and `--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci` are the correct ones to set both, the character set and collation to `UTF-8`.

Now my questions is: how do I get rid of that `utf8mb3` value for `character_set_system`? It should be set to `utf8mb4` along with the other values — or that's what I think ;)

Any clues how to set this correctly?

> I would like to avoid using any configuration file(s) (like `my.cnf`) since I'm using the stock Docker image without any modifications.

Comment: You can usually volume mount a cnf file but watch out for [this issue](https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-docker/issues/327) that I should correct. From docs [character_set_system](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#character_set_system) is a fixed value but maybe this fixed value changed in [the recent server changes](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-1061-release-notes/#character-sets).

Comment: I think that's the reason (last link): _the `utf8` character set (and related collations) is now by default an alias for `utf8mb3` rather than the other way around_. Since the value for `character_set_system` is fixed, and always `utf8`, now it's showing up as `utf8mb3` instead. I will accept your answer if you would like to write your comment as such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

character_set_system specifies the character set which will be used to store identifiers and other internal information.

It is 3byte utf8, and you cannot change it unless you change sources and recompile MariaDB.

Beginning with 10.6, utf8 was mapped to utf8mb3 (and will be mapped to utf8mb4 in later versions). See [MDEV-8334](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-8334)

Answer (score 5):

I am having a similar problem in MariaDB 10.6.5, I was trying to load a dump from AWS and had this error:

```
ERROR 1253 (42000) at line 26: COLLATION 'utf8mb3_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4'
```

My config looks like this:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%char%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_system     | utf8mb3                    |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

and according to this page https://mariadb.com/kb/en/old-mode/ I had to set `old-mode` to empty in `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf`

> old-mode=

Therefore it changed from

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%old%';
+------------------------------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name                            | Value           |
+------------------------------------------+-----------------+
| old_mode                                 | UTF8_IS_UTF8MB3 |
+--------------------------+---------------------------------+
```

to

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%old%';
+------------------------------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name                            | Value           |
+------------------------------------------+-----------------+
| old_mode                                 |                 |
+--------------------------+---------------------------------+
```

So I've managed to load the SQL dump even if `character_set_system` was still showing `utf8mb3`.

HTH somebody.